# Custom handler class method handleMessage() not trigerred

Tags: java, android, handler, message

I have a utility class where I attempt to send a message. I also created a custom Handler class to handle the messages response. The problem is that `handleMessage(Message msg)` is not getting called at all. Is it that I'm understanding something incorrectly?

I've tried playing around with placing the handler in different areas of the app structure but I still don't receive any messages.

Below are the public methods that I use in my utility class to send the message into the queue:

```
    public boolean sendRequestToService(int what, Bundle data){

        boolean ok = false;
        Message message = new Message();
        message.what = what;

        if(data!=null){
            message.setData(data);
        }

        if (null != mService) {
            try {
                mService.send(message);
                ok = true;
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return ok;
    }

    private void registerToService() {
        try {
            Message msg = Message.obtain(null, 14);

            Messenger mFromService = new Messenger(new MyAppHandler(this));

            msg.replyTo = mFromService;
            if (null != mService) {
                mService.send(msg);
            }

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        }
    }

/////////////////////////////
//////MyAppHandler.java//////
/////////////////////////////
    public class MyAppHandler extends Handler implements BluetoothAPI {

         private BluetoothDataListener dataListener;

         public MyAppHandler(BluetoothDataListener dataListener){
             super();
             this.dataListener = dataListener;
         }


         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
             System.out.println("handle message");
         }
     }
```